# How to refrence pod's shell env variable in configmap data section

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, micronaut, configmap

I have a configmap.yaml file as below :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: abc
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: abc
    version: 0.17.0
data:
  application.yml: |-
    myjava:
      security:
        enabled: true
    abc:
      server:
        access-log: 
          enabled: ${myvar}. ## this is not working
```

"myvar" value is available in pod as shell environment variable from secretkeyref field in deployment file.

Now I want to replace myvar shell environment variable in configmap above i.e before application.yml file is available in pod it should have replaced myvar value. which is not working i tried ${myvar} and $(myvar) and "#{ENV['myvar']}"

Is that possible in kubernetes configmap to reference with in data section pod's environment variable if yes how or should i need to write a script to replace with sed -i application.yml etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that possible in kubernetes configmap to reference with in data section pod's environment variable

That's not possible. A `ConfigMap` is not associated with a particular pod, so there's no way to perform the sort of variable substitution you're asking about. You would need to implement this logic inside your containers (fetch the `ConfigMap`, perform variable substitution yourself, then consume the data).

Comment: Problem is configmap mounted as read only so can not modify data in configmap with sed like utility

Comment: The fact that they are read-only doesn't matter. You can use `sed` (or other tool) to produce a *new file*.